# Styled Components / focus

Tags: css, styled-components

Hello i wanted that when a component (h3 or div bg img)
are on hover or on focus
increase the h3's brightness and apply box-shadow to bg img

i can't imagine how to do this with styled components
my code:

```
 <Styled.CardTop background={TestBG3}>
    <div className="Bg" />
    <div className="headerH3">
    <h3>aaaaaaaaa.</h3>
    </div>
  </Styled.CardTop>
```

css with styled comp:

```
const CardTop = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  & .Bg {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(${({ background }) => background});
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    cursor:pointer;
    :hover{
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
}
  & .headerH3 {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#1976d2;
  :hover,:active{
    filter: brightness(115%);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use &:hover, &:active.
My example is slightly different from yours but you can see that hover is working

https://codesandbox.io/s/style-with-styled-components-30zww

Comment: Hello , I want to apply a css to my h1 and my img when one of the two is on hover or on focus

Comment: You can use sibling selectors (as in css https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) but it will work only for the next sibling - as i did in the example. Or you can use React state - keep isHover boolean which will be updated when one of the elements is hovered and then apply the desired css.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I can tell if an element of mine is on hover by useState? -

Comment: Here, the example with hover in React state: https://codesandbox.io/s/style-with-styled-components-b4hmu